# Problema al guardar etiquetas HTML en mysql con LARAVEL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, formularios, ckeditor

Tengo un editor de texto con CKEDITOR5 y lo estoy implementando en Laravel, todo funciona como debe, pero al momento de hacer submit y guardar los textos, solo se guardan los textos pero sin las etiquetas que se supone fueron generadas con CKeditor. Revisando el codigo, estoy seguro que el editor esta generando las etiquetas correctamente, pero cuando recibo la informacion en el controlador, los campos vienen sin las etiquetas, aqui adjunto el codigo:

Aqui, el blade:

```html
 <form action="{{route('setting.post')}}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form_post">
@csrf
<div class="row">
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="title_post">Title:</label>
<input type="text" name="title_post" class="form-control" placeholder="Title of post">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
<label for="image_post">Image:</label>
<input type="file" name="image_post" class="form-control" accept="image/*">
</div>
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
<label for="description_post">Description:</label>
<textarea name="description_post" class="form-control" id="description_post"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="htmlValor" value="" id="htmlValor">
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-right">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-rounded">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Aqui la funcion del controlador:

```js
public function postBlog(Request $request)
        {   
            $request->validate([
                'image_post' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
            ]);

            $image = $request->file('image_post');
            $description = html_entity_decode($request->input('description_post'));
            $filename = $image->hashName();

            $image->move(public_path('assets/images/postImages'), $filename);
            
            // dd( $description);

            Blog::create([ 
                'title' => $request->input('title_post'),
                'description' => $description,
                'image' => $filename,
            ]);
            
            return redirect('home');


        }
```

Datos enviados:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Datos recibidios:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el payload que esta enviando el formulario, justamente como sale en el payload es como lo quiero almacenar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ojala y puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias de antemano

Comment: Una cosa es cómo se genere el valor, otra como se transmita, otra como lo manipules, otra como se represente/visualice/decodifique, pero lo mas es importante saber es ¿Cómo quieres que se almacene? ¿Por qué usas `html_entity_decode()`?.

Comment: Eso fue un intento de mi parte que no funcionó. Necesito que se almacene con las etiquetas HTML generadas del ckeditor, ya que después de eso tendré que pintar la información en otra vista. Y necesito que se pinte igual a como la persona escriba en el editor, espero darme a entender

Comment: Mira en la pestaña network de las herramientas del navegador si en el body del request los datos salen con las etiquetas desde ahí o ya no las tiene

Comment: Bueno, primero que nada, gracias por tu ayuda amigo. Revisando el netword, estoy viendo que el payload se esta enviando justamente como yo quiero, con las etiquetas. Arriba modifique la pregunta para mostrar como esta enviando la data

Answer (score 0):

despues de quitarme el sueñ y dudar de mis capacidades,  logre solucionar mi problema. Realmente aun no se por que el `$request->input('description_post')` elimina las etiquetas html. Tuve que usar la vieja confiable: `$description_post = $_POST['description_post'];` con ésto, al fin pude almacenar la data del ckeditor con las etiquetas html que éste genera. La funcion `postBlog()` quedo de la siguiente manera:

```
public function postBlog(Request $request)
    {               
        $request->validate([
            'image_post' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
        ]);

        $image = $request->file('image_post');
        $filename = $image->hashName();

        $image->move(public_path('assets/images/postImages'), $filename);

        $description_post = $_POST['description_post'];
        Blog::create([ 
            'title' => $request->input('title_post'),
            'description' => $description_post,
            'image' => $filename,
        ]);
   
        return redirect('home');
    }
```

Espero que a alguien mas le sirva esta informacion.